# Galaxy S1 won't read SIM card

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

I switched my SIM card to the Galaxy S1 it reads it but under my network it says "unknown" so i can't send/ receive messages or calls why?

Comment: Switched it from where?  Did you activate your new phone on that sim card?  Need more details!

Comment: Please provide more information so user are able to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the battery and leave for 10minutes before replacing. This will allow any residual memory in your phone to leak and give a cleaner network link.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest install a app to read the detailed info. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidyou.simcardinfo&hl=en

if it says unknown, it basically means it can't read the sim